# How to call a loop under main fuction python

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am working on a script which i have to modify in order loop through the multiple resources within a functions.

Below are the items which we need to loop through to get the data from and, this is coming from `Config_local`

```
BASE_URL = "https://synergy.hpe.example.com/rest/"

RES_EXT = [ 'resource-alerts?count=500&start=1',
            'resource-alerts?count=500&start=501' 
            'resource-alerts?count=500&start=1001,
            'resource-alerts?count=500&start=1501'
            ]
```

While i am looping through above list under `def main():` section and taking `get_resource_alerts_response()` under loop the data coming out of the loop getting over-written and thus returning only last loop data only.

### Main Script:

```
import os
import shutil
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)
import requests
from Config_local import (
    BASE_URL,
    DST_DIR,
    OUTFILE,
    PASSWORD,
    SRC_DIR,
    TIMESTAMP_DST,
    USERNAME,
    SUBJECT,
    FROM,
    TO,
    EMAIL_TEMPLATE,
    SMTP_SERVER,
    RES_EXT,
)

class FileMoveFailure(Exception):
    pass

class SynergyRequestFailure(Exception):
    pass

class SessionIdRetrievalFailure(SynergyRequestFailure):
    pass

class ResourceAlertsRetrievalFailure(SynergyRequestFailure):
    pass

def move_csv_files():
    for csv_file in os.listdir(SRC_DIR):
        if csv_file.endswith(".csv") and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(SRC_DIR, csv_file)):
            try:
                shutil.move(
                    os.path.join(f"{SRC_DIR}/{csv_file}"),
                    f"{DST_DIR}/{csv_file}-{TIMESTAMP_DST}.log"
                )
            except OSError as os_error:
                raise FileMoveFailure(
                    f'Moving file {csv_file} has failed: {os_error}'
                )

def get_session_id(session):
    try:
        response = session.post(
            url=f"{BASE_URL}/login-sessions",
            headers={
                "accept": "application/json",
                "content-type": "application/json",
                "x-api-version": "120",
            },
            json={
                "userName": USERNAME,
                "password": PASSWORD
            },
            verify=False
        )
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as req_exception:
        # you should also get this logged somewhere, or at least
        # printed depending on your use case
        raise SessionIdRetrievalFailure(
            f"Could not get session id: {req_exception}"
        )

    json_response = response.json()
    if not json_response.get("sessionID"):
        # always assume the worse and do sanity checks & validations
        # on fetched data
        raise KeyError("Could not fetch session id")
    return json_response["sessionID"]

#def get_all_text(session, session_id):
#    all_text = ''
#    for res in RES_EXT:
#        url= f"{BASE_URL}{res}"
#        newresult = get_resource_alerts_response(session, session_id, url)
#        all_text += newresult
#        print(f"{all_text}")
#        return str(all_text)
#

def get_resource_alerts_response(session, session_id, res):
    try:
        return  session.get(
            url=f"{BASE_URL}{res}",
            headers={
                "accept": "application/json",
                "content-type": "text/csv",
                "x-api-version": "2",
                "auth": session_id,
            },
            verify=False,
            stream=True
        )
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as req_exception:
        # you should also get this logged somewhere, or at least
        # printed depending on your use case
        raise ResourceAlertsRetrievalFailure(
            f"Could not fetch resource alerts: {req_exception}"
        )

def resource_alerts_to_df(resource_alerts_response):
    with open(OUTFILE, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in resource_alerts_response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024*36):
            f.write(chunk)
    return pd.read_csv(OUTFILE)

def send_email(df):
    server = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER)
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'], msg['From'], msg['To'] = SUBJECT, FROM, TO
    msg.set_content("Text version of your html template")
    msg.add_alternative(
        EMAIL_TEMPLATE.format(df.to_html(index=False)),
        subtype='html'
    )
    server.send_message(msg)

def main():
    move_csv_files()
    session = requests.Session()
    session_id = get_session_id(session)
    for res in RES_EXT:
        resource_alerts_response = get_resource_alerts_response(session,
        session_id, res)
        print(resource_alerts_response)
    df = resource_alerts_to_df(resource_alerts_response)
    print(df)
    send_email(df)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

any help or hint will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can’t you just put the df = resource_alerts_to_df(...) inside the loop and then append to another dataframe to aggregate results across the iterations?

Comment: @RolandASc, may if you can show that so as to test, that will help.

Comment: @kulfi I've added an updated my answer below with two different approaches to solving your issue.

Comment: @ggordon,  Second solution sending only one e-mail but again not clubbing all the data.

Comment: @kulfi my apologies, I forgot to re-assign the value i.e. `df_resource_alerts_responses = df_resource_alerts_responses.append(df, ignore_index=True)`. I've updated `Option 2` in the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a copy of the code which I recall we had over SO but not what you want now, However, as the whole code body is okay and the idea of `for loop` is also looks good, you Just need to tweek it to meet the requirement.

1- You need to create and empty DataFrame assignment `Synergy_Data = pd.DataFrame()`

2- then you can append the data you received from `for loop` ie `resource_alerts_response` which becomes `df = resource_alerts_to_df(resource_alerts_response)`

3- lastly, you can append this `df` to the empty `Synergy_Data` and then call that under your `if __name__ == '__main__'`  to send an e-mail. Also don't forget to declare `Synergy_Data` as a `global` variable.

```
Synergy_Data = pd.DataFrame()

def main():
    global Synergy_Data
    move_csv_files()
    session = requests.Session()
    session_id = get_session_id(session)
    for res in RES_EXT:
        resource_alerts_response = get_resource_alerts_response(session,
        session_id, res)
        df = resource_alerts_to_df(resource_alerts_response)
        Synergy_Data = Synergy_Data.append(df)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    send_email(Synergy_Data)
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Is a global variable necessary when the data is being passed as a parameter to the `send_email` function. This global variable will use memory when not in use.

Comment: @ggordon, this is necessary as it will produce `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Synergy_Data' referenced before assignment` , there may be a better way to improve it though. from [Python documentation,](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)  it says,  you can access the outer scope variable by declaring it global.

Answer (score 1):

Only the last response is being used because this value is overwritten in `resource_alerts_response` on each iteration of the loop. You may consider acting on the data on each iteration or storing it for use later i.e. after the loop. I've included these options with modifications to the `main()` function below.

### Option 1

Send an email for each resource alert response

```py
def main():
    move_csv_files()
    session = requests.Session()
    session_id = get_session_id(session)
    for res in RES_EXT:
        resource_alerts_response = get_resource_alerts_response(session,
        session_id, res)
        print(resource_alerts_response)

        # Indent lines below so that the operations below are executed in each loop iteration
        df = resource_alerts_to_df(resource_alerts_response)
        print(df)
        send_email(df)
```

### Option 2

Merge all resource alert responses and send one email

```py
def main():
    move_csv_files()
    session = requests.Session()
    session_id = get_session_id(session)
    df_resource_alerts_responses = None
    for res in RES_EXT:
        resource_alerts_response = get_resource_alerts_response(session,
        session_id, res)
        print(resource_alerts_response)
        df = resource_alerts_to_df(resource_alerts_response)
        if df_resource_alerts_responses is None:
            df_resource_alerts_responses = df
        else:
            df_resource_alerts_responses = df_resource_alerts_responses.append(df, ignore_index=True)
    print(df_resource_alerts_responses)
    if  df_resource_alerts_responses is not None:
        send_email(df_resource_alerts_responses)
```